# Is there any way to fix the data position in datagridview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

For example : if admin can view all data in a grid. when logged in as faculty, he/she can view only his/her data in the grid and the rest must be hidden to them. By changing the sql query Im able to filter based on `facultyID`(primary) but while displaying the position in the grid changes because of the while loop. Suggest me a solution

```
private void FillDisGrid()

    {
         int a1 = 0;
         int colNo = 1;
         if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) { conn.Close(); }
         conn.Open();
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
         SqlDataReader dr;
         cmd.Connection = conn;
         cmd.CommandText = "select Subjectname,FacultyID from timetabletab where FacultyID='" + comboBox2.Text + "' and semester='" + comboBox3.Text + "' order by rno";
         dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         while (dr.Read())
         {
             if (colNo % 6 == 0) { colNo = 1; a1 = a1 + 2; }
             dataGridView1.Rows[a1].Cells[colNo].Value = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
             dataGridView1.Rows[a1 + 1].Cells[colNo].Value = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
             colNo++;

         }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what the code is supposed to be doing. A real-world example would be nice

Comment: Imagine a school timetable.If Im a student I can view my class entire timetable.If Im a teacher I can view only my subjects in the timetable.Here, I can filter easily just by changing the query.But while displaying the subject positions are also changing.How to keep it fixed

Answer (score 0):

So you want one grid that can display different data and headers based on which person is viewing?  If so you can try this, when you get the data from the database, have it come back in a datatable or a custom object, bind that to the grid.  but set the grid AutoGenerateColumns = false, so it will only generate the headers based on what was bound to it.